# SharePoint security update with issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-admin-center

I have an issue with installing Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB4484443)
after it is installed all asp.net forms are no longer use client validation

Answer (score 0):

If the issue occurs right after installing the SU, I will suggest you to open a support ticket.